Custom authentication. Registration scenario
I feel ashamed to ask such common question, but I can't find the answer on the internet, how should my authentication work during registration scenario.
I am using asp.net core, once you enable authentication there it will invoke on each request your api receives.
I am writing custom handler to process authentication, which using jwt token approach.
And one of the scenarios when user trying to register in the system, so he doesn't have jwt token yet.
Should I just return return AuthenticateResult.Success if path contains "register" ?
Or I must do something else ?

Use the built-in methods:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-9.0&tabs=visual-studio
